# How to prevent Uncaught DOMException when checking selector in document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, queryselector

in JavaScript I have code like:

```
var text = '[0-9]';
if (document.querySelector(text) !== null) {
alert('fail');
}
```

When I run it, there is an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
> 'Document': '[0-9]' is not a valid selector.

Please how to check if querySelector is valid or invalid without this error?

I want to have ability to write anything to variable "text" and I want the code to alert "failed" when it is not valid selector. Without that error, no matter what variable "text" contains.

Comment: surround it in a `try...catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to prevent the error

```
let text = '[0-9]';
if (getQuerySelector(text) !== null) {
    alert('fail');
}

function getQuerySelector(txt){
  try {
    return document.querySelector(txt);
  } 
  catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```